# JSP store form data

Tags: jsp

I have two pages: at `first.jsp` user enters some data, then goes to `second.jsp`, than returns back to the `first.jsp`. So I need to store user input from `first.jsp` *somewhere* and then return it to the form.

I can pass data to `second.jsp`, store it there, and pass it back into `first.jsp`, but it's looks like really bad solution.

Is it any other solution?

Comment: Use the MCV design pattern.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis You mean MVC ?

Comment: Have you tried to add the user input information to session variables or attributes? if you store them into the user session it will be able in any jsp or servlet running on the application. Add it to session after the get/post from first.jsp to second.jsp and check the existence of the attributes each time the implied jsps are requested by user.

Comment: @yashpandey Thank you, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HttpSession` object to store/retrieve the objects across multiple JSP pages and you can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) on this.

Basically, you need to set `httpSession.setAttribute("DATAKEY", dataObj);` and then retrieve the data again using `httpSession.getAttribute("DATAKEY");`

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.